# Swift Charts Animation works editing values but not entering one new

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-charts

I expect the line grow with animation when entering a new entry but the animation only happen when editing existing values

I don't want a canvas resize so I need to scale the canvas before the animation.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Entry: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var time: Double
    var value: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data: [Entry] = [
        .init(time: 0, value: 0),
        .init(time: 1, value: 1)]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("+"){
                withAnimation{
                    data.append(.init(time: 2, value: 2))
                }
            }
            Chart(data){entry in
                LineMark(x: .value("time", entry.time),
                         y: .value("value", entry.value))
            }
            .chartXScale(domain: 0...2)
            .chartYScale(domain: 0...2)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see animated? By setting the domains on the two scales, they are already sized appropriately for the point you are adding so no scale change is required.

Comment: I expect the line go from (1,1) to (2,3) without a canvas resize

Comment: That's exactly what I am seeing. No resize, just an extension to the line when the point is added. Tried on iPhone 14 Pro and iPad mini 6G (iOS 16.4).

Comment: with animation? I'm testing in iOS 17

Comment: Animation of what? No resize = no animation. The extension to the line is animated, but it goes so quickly you hardly notice. It's more noticeable when the new point is way off the scale.

Comment: Line is not animated . Tested with  an animation modifier with 3 seconds of duration: `.animation(.easeIn(duration:3), value: data)`